# Gradient descent based search in spatial domain

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

My question might seem trivial but after much searching I am unable to find the answer.

My question is that is it possible to use gradient descent for finding the minima (conversely maxima as well) while searching a physical space. As an example, we are interested in finding the minima or maxima of a radio signal broadcasted in space. The signal will have a global minima as well as local minima as it propagates in space. The signal is not changing over time.
For this radiation pattern is it possible or advisable to implement gradient descent for searching the minima/maxima?
If yes than, how would you model the cost function in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your task differ from using gradient descent to find a local optimum of a function, in anything other than that it has an interpretation in physical space?

Comment: No. If I could precisely model the function in real physical space and find a mathematical model for its spatial distribution then its not different.
However, it is obviously not feasible/possible to have a precise mathematical model of the signal. That's why I want to use gradient descent based search to find physical minima/maxima

Comment: Can you measure the gradient of the signal directly?

Comment: If I go about sampling the signal in space at random points, I can find the difference in signal level at those points. That could serve as a gradient but as I said in question I don't have a cost function / model to find gradient

Comment: An estimation of gradient should work also. However, there are optimisation methods which don't require the gradient at all. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization